# What does this geometric objects combinations mean?

Tags: visual, number-sequence

You see combinations of geometric objects from a circle, a triangle, a square, a rectangle and a diamond and corresponding them numbers $4, 6, 19, 190, 1900$.

**Question** Can you define the number for the bottom row?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 2021

Reasoning

> Each shape represents a Roman numeral
>  Circle is I,
>  Triangle is V,
>  Square is X,
>  Long Rectangle is C,
>  Diamond is M.
>  So the last sequence represents **MMXXI** which is **2021**.